# would not vs won't

Tags: will-would

I was wondering which form of sentence is correct?

> 1)I'm going to be so disappointed if he won't receive a reward tomorrow.
>
> 2)I'm going to be so disappointed if he wouldn't receive a reward tomorrow.

In this situation, I'm talking about willing him to receive a reward but it depends on the person giving the award to get one. So he's not deciding.
Thanks.

Comment: isn't it something happening in the future and not always?so why shouldn't I use the future form?

Comment: @Mag This is somewhat basic English and the answer should be readily accessible in any beginner's grammar book or online grammar site, which is why I'm voting to close for lack of research. I recommend you visit our sibling site ELL and search for questions under the [future-tense tag](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/future-tense). ELL is a great site for other questions you might have as you develop your English proficiency. :-)

Answer (score 2):

- **Won't** is short for **will not**
- **Wouldn't** is short for **would not**

Neither 'will' nor 'would'  are correct for future conditional tense. The correct word is **does**.

> If he **does** receive an award then I will applaud.

So the correct long form of your sentence is:

> I'm going to be so disappointed if he **does** not receive a reward tomorrow.

You can abbreviate that to *doesn't*.

Comment: What "future conditional tense"?

Comment: Not only is there no "future conditional tense" in English, there is not even a _future_ tense. If you need to resort to using ESL jargon to explain something  then that should be an indicator that this Q should be either a) migrated to ELL, or b) closed for lack of research. And that is why we often answer these in comments...